# Why is waiting for Condition in a while loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

From the official [Java Documentation of the class `Condition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)

```
public void put(E x) throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        while (count == items.length)
            notFull.await();

        items[putptr] = x;

        if (++putptr == items.length)
            putptr = 0;

        ++count;
        notEmpty.signal();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

What is the role of having `notFull.await()` in a `while` loop? I am not seeing what this does. Can anyone provide a simple explanation?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the `while` loop is explained in the [Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) documentation:

> When waiting upon a Condition, a "spurious wakeup" is permitted to
>   occur, in general, as a concession to the underlying platform
>   semantics. This has little practical impact on most application
>   programs as a Condition should always be waited upon in a loop,
>   testing the state predicate that is being waited for. An
>   implementation is free to remove the possibility of spurious wakeups
>   **but it is recommended that applications programmers always assume that
>   they can occur and so always wait in a loop**.

Comment: So when I did `notFull.await()` that thread went to *sleep* and then needs to be woken up with `notFull.signal()` so that it can once again check the condition `count == items.length`. This `while(count == items.length)` loop **only runs TWICE** though right? First time to put to sleep, second time after its signaled to wake up and then again check?

Comment: As said in the documentation the thread might be woken up spuriously even if it wasn't signalled to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are two waiting threads. Both get notified. Only one of them should move forward. Another have to re-check and wait.

Comment: In this case, is the only reason we use `notFull.wait()` so that we can allow other threads to come in? 


I don't see the point of using `await()` then because we are at the end of the day still checking the `count == items.length` condition. What is the point of `await` or `signal` then?